# Is There A Way To Undo All Actions Before I Quit Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I made some changes to my project tonight and messed some stuff up.  Is there a way I can go back to how the project was when I opened it?  I added/deleted some files but I don't see a way to go back.  My last time machine backup was from a few days ago also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't help with the immediate problem, but you need to start using source code control.

This is exactly the sort of problem that source control solves. In Xcode 4 Apple make it particularly easy to start using source code control, as whenever you create a project it offers to create a Git repository for you.

Even for the smallest personal projects, source control is well worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why my project didn't have it.  It usually comes with the option enabled with xcode 4.  Is there anyway I can add this to my project?

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility to roll back changes if you use XCode's [snapshots](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/SCM/SCM.html) feature. XCode 4 suggests making a project snapshot before refactoring, for example.

If you don't have the habit to commit or stash changes often (or happen not to use source control at all), snapshots are a nice tool to use before making any major changes that may break the project.

In your current situation though, you're out of luck. Sorry.